# angular custom directive 404 on template URL

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Update : ** this is running on localhost.

Here is my controller :

```
app.controller('adsController',
    ['$scope',
    function($scope){

    $scope.obj = {
       prop : "Hello"
    }
}])
```

The directive :

```
app.directive('ads', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: { obj: '=' },
        templateUrl: '/modules/ads/templates/ads-template.html'
    };
});
```

The directory :

[image]

I'm invoking the `<ads/>` custom directive from the same depth in directory as the `ads-template.html` But im having a `404` error.

[image]

Comment: Your file has a typo in its name.

Comment: @BroiSatse that was a stupid mistake lol. I corrected the file name. The problem still exists.

Comment: Is your server serving modules folder as static asset?

Comment: @BroiSatse yes. BTW im on the localhost

Comment: @BroiSatse it's weird. I removed the first `/` and it worked. `"modules/...."`

Comment: Be careful with that - using relative paths caused me a lot of trouble once. Have a look at the current url it uses now to fetch the view.

Comment: @BroiSatse `http://localhost/my-app/modules/ads/templates/ads-template.html` still the same as when i'm using relative path. Im not sure yet if non-relative path will work in `html5mode`. Will update this question once I figured out. 

Can you provide a detailed answer so the future viewers of this question will find it helpful? Thanks.